# Undefined error while exporting variable in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is my managedb.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-postgres').sequelize;
var postgres  = require('sequelize-postgres').postgres;

 var db = new Sequelize('test', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
  dialect: 'postgres'
});


var models = [
'user'
];

models.forEach(function(model) {
module.exports[model] = db.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
});



module.exports.db = db;
```

This is my user.js

```
var sequelize = require("sequelize");
var seq = require("./managedb");
var db = seq.db;

var Project = db.define('Project', {
  title: sequelize.STRING,
  description: sequelize.TEXT
});
```

I'm confused why I'm getting this error:

```
var Project = db.define('Project', {
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'define' of undefined
```

Why is this being caused? Am I exporting the variables wrong? Or do I've to add a db.sync() statement to managedb.js?

Comment: Have you verified that calling `db.define` inside managedb.js works? That would tell you whether the problem has anything to do with exporting.

Comment: Yup, just checked and it works though it gives a SQL error while creating the table. Nothing to do with db.define

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you have posted which would preclude `module.exports.db = db;` from working. Is there more code in managedb.js? Something that would cause `db` to be destroyed, or the export statement to be never reached, or reached asynchronously (which would be too late)? You could put in `console.log` statements right after mod.exports, and right before db.define and make sure they occur in the order you expect. Just some thoughts.

Comment: I did check again var seq = require("./managedb");
console.log(seq); and this returned {} I presumably am going wrong here.

Comment: Like I said, make sure the module.exports statements being reached (and not asynchronously).

Comment: I removed this code: models.forEach(function(model) {
module.exports[model] = db.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
});
 and it started working. Completely confused why, though

Comment: That is confusing. I copied your foreach into my own test (minus the `db.import` since I don't have postgres setup) and all of the exports worked as expected.

Comment: I think I found the issue. The problem is here: module.exports[model] = db.import(__dirname + '/' + model); which returns {} but I'm not sure how to solve this.